# Shuffling a Stack<T>

Tags: c#, list, generics, stack, shuffle

```
    public static void Shuffle<T> ( this Stack<T> stack )
    {
        List<T> list = stack.ToList ();
        list.Shuffle ();
        stack = list.ToStack ();
    }

    public static void Shuffle<T> ( this List<T> list )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ )
        {
            int num = Form1.rnd.Next ( list.Count );
            T temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[num];
            list[num] = temp;
        }
    }

    public static Stack<T> ToStack<T> ( this List<T> list )
    {
        Stack<T> stack = new Stack<T> ();
        foreach ( T t in list )
            stack.Push ( t );

        return stack;
    }
```

Above is my attempt to shuffle a generic stack. However, although the List Shuffle extension method works, the Stack Shuffle does not work as intended. It is as if the Shuffle call in the middle isn't called at all. Instead, it remains the same list, un-shuffled. So I presume the problem is in the ToStack function. Can someone please explain my error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't the parameter type be `ref` or `out` to let the caller *see* your changes to the input `stack` argument?

Comment: Also Nick, if you create a new instance of random at the start of your loop `var rnd = new Random()` and then `int num = rnd.Next ( list.Count );`, you will be able to get rid of your dependency on Form1 and use these methods anywhere.

Comment: @ray, you cannot use `ref` or `out` on the first parameter in extension methods. OP would have to convert these methods to normal methods if he wants to use `ref` or `out`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad: Thanks for the clarification. Read a bit more on extension methods, since I had not used them and the `this` at the beginning was odd to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you're assigning a new instance of `Stack<T>` to a local variable, which means the calling stack variable isn't changed.

Now you could add a `ref` to the parameter, but I generally try to avoid doing that.

Here are two alternatives.

If you want to keep using the same reference then you can do this:

```
public static void Shuffle<T>(this Stack<T> stack)
{
    var values = stack.ToArray();
    stack.Clear();
    foreach (var value in values.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()))
        stack.Push(value);
}
```

This is fairly simple and avoids the need to call a separate method to shuffle.

Or, you can return a new instance of `Stack<T>`.

```
public static Stack<T> Shuffle<T>(this Stack<T> stack)
{
    return new Stack<T>(stack.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()));
}
```

This again avoids the need to call a separate shuffle method.

Both methods use `.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())` to perform the shuffle which is much easier than swapping indices around.

Comment: Side note: OrderBy is slower than Fisher-Yates shuffle shown in the question... But definitely easier to get right :).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 6):

The `Shuffle` method (that takes a  `Stack<T>`) takes the stack parameter by value. So when you invoke `stack = list.ToStack ();`, you are changing a variable (`stack`) that is local to the method.

One solution is to do as you did with the `List<T>` shuffle method like this:

```
public static Stack<T> Shuffle<T>(this Stack<T> stack)
{
    List<T> list = stack.ToList();
    list.Shuffle();
    return list.ToStack();
}
```

This method takes a stack as input as generates a new shuffled stack. You can use it like this:

```
Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    stack.Push(i);

stack = stack.Shuffle();
```

Comment: I think that `public static void Shuffle<T> ( this List<T> list )` would also be nicer if it were `public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T> ( this List<T> list )` that would return the shuffled list.

Comment: But wouldn't the stack parameter be a reference to the instance of the Stack<T> since it is a extension method?

Comment: Extension methods are just clever syntactic sugar for static methods. The `this` allows that magic, but doesnt make the local stop behaving like a local inside a method.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you!